# How is the health restored by the Dew Vial determined?

Tags: pixel-dungeon

The Dew Vial is definitely a good idea, but I'm wondering how it works.

When you drink the dew (or when it is automatically drank at low health), how is the amount of health calculated? Is it `amount of dewdrops in bottle` times `ceiling(level/5)` or does it count up the worth of each dew drop according to when you pick it up? (Remember, dewdrops count for 1 HP in levels 1-5, 2 HP in levels 6-10, etc.)

Whenever I drink a full dew vial I usually find myself near max health, so I'm guessing that my first thought is correct. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Juergen Hartelt is entirely wrong.

Dewdrop Vial can hold up to 10 drops.
Each drop restores 10% of your maximum Health

So ..

(drop_num/10*maxhp)

3drops/10*60maxhp === 18hp

http://pixeldungeon.wikia.com/wiki/Dew_vial

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

The author Watabou wrote in his blog, that the health restored by the vial scales with the number of drops collected: http://pixeldungeon.tumblr.com/day/2014/02/04

So one drop restores 1 health; 10 drops restore all health.

Comment: For future reference: One drop restores 10% of health rather than 1 HP.